# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seek'

Tags: python, nlp

When I try the codes below,

```
posts = nltk.corpus.nps_chat.xml_posts()[:10000]

def dialogue_act_features(post, i):
    features = {}
    text = nltk.word_tokenize(post.text)
    for word in text:
        features['contains(%s)' % word.lower()] = True
    if i > 0:
        features["prev-tag"] = posts[i-1].get('class')
    else:
        features["prev-tag"] = '<Start>'
    return features

featuresets = []
for (i, post) in enumerate(posts):
    featuresets.append((dialogue_act_features(post, i), post.get('class')))
```

The error information is following:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python Practice/NLP/Chapter6_exercises.py", line 180, in <module>
    for (i, post) in enumerate(posts):
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\util.py", line 412, in iterate_from
    for tok in piece.iterate_from(max(0, start_tok - offset)):
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\util.py", line 293, in iterate_from
    self._stream.seek(filepos)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: looks like `posts` has different structure than you expected. Try to print it...

Comment: @rzlvmp It goes well, 
```
for (i, post) in enumerate(posts[:10000]):
    print(i, post.text, post.get('class'))
```
and here is part of the result:
~~~python
9997 wheeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee Emotion
9998 PART System
9999 I hate you, 11-09-teensUser122. Statement
~~~